# Tool for logging NIC link state events

Tags: windows, networking, logging

Intel NICs have a driver option (in Windows) that will log link state events to the system log, so if the network drops out periodically you can determine that fact.

Does anyone know of a simple generic solution that does this, in other words one that is not part of the driver from a particular manufacturer?

I know there are plenty of 'big iron' network monitoring tools out there but surely there's something really simple that runs as a service in Windows with minimal setup ?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcoms come with BACS to manage these things, and I think windows system logs should also log NIC disconnects.

Comment: I don't think Windows logs them directly - you might see errors accessing a domain server or whatever but not 'The adapter link state has changed to disconnected.' or whatever.

Comment: The system detected that network adapter \DEVICE\TCPIP_{5DBC2B8F-BD17-4F0C-BED7-C1B75FDA9D51} was connected to the network, and has initiated normal operation over the network adapter.

I get this when I disconnect and reconnect the NIC on my winXP